# How do I show the unique values?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am working on Google Sheet Tables and I want to get in a column the unique values ​​of the list:

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
4
5
```

But I just want to output this:

```
4
5
```

So I just want to see the absolutely unique values.
Does somebody has any idea?

Comment: Unique() or the remove duplicates button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in row 1 (any Col but the list of values):

```
=filter(A1:A,countif(A1:A,A1:A)=1)
```